# How to interpret sum contrast in logistic regression

Tags: regression, logistic, contrasts

I have a two level factor (treatment 1 and treatment 2) and I want to explore the influence of this factor into a binomial factor (death, yes no, with ref=no). I would like to obtain an odds ratio, but I do not want to contrast treatment 1 vs treatment 2. I would like to contrast treatment 1 vs mean and treatment 2 vs mean.

I was exploring the use of contrast sum, but when I obtain the coefficients in the model I do not know how to interpret them. If I exponentiate the coefficient, I guess it is and OR, but I cannot know the sense of it. Does and OR > 1 mean treatment 1 increases the likelihood of death.